# Code throws an error in the Android emulator, but not in Eclipse. Textview change on button click

Tags: button, android-emulator, textview, runtime-error, imagebutton

I'm a new Android application developer, and I want an application that changes a textview widget by clicking a button. Eclipse does not throw and error, but the Android emulator does throw an error.

Here is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int stringIdList[] = { R.string.text1, R.string.text2, R.string.text3,
        R.string.text4 };
int stringListCounter = 0;
TextView text122;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Next);
    ImageButton previous = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Previous);
    text122 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text00);
    next.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    previous.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    if (id == R.id.Next && stringListCounter < stringIdList.length - 1) {
        stringListCounter++;
    } else if (id == R.id.Previous && stringListCounter > 0) {
        stringListCounter--;
    }

    text122.setText(stringIdList[stringListCounter]);
}
```

}

and my layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text00"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/Next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Text00"
    android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="268dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Text00"
    android:contentDescription="dgdfgd"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/Previous"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="127dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Text00"
    android:contentDescription="dsfsf"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my logcat error contains

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nar.yeni/com.nar.yeni.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nar.yeni.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
```

Comment: Please edit to include the error messages.

Comment: i added something from logcat i don't know is it enough??

Comment: When does it crash?  On launch?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in

```
    next.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    previous.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

I'm not sure why you're setting your onClick listeners that way since I'm not that proficient either.

Here's how I learned it

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int stringIdList[] = { 111, 222, 333, 444};
    int stringListCounter = 0;
    TextView text122;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setWidgets();
        setOnClickListeners();
    }

    private void setWidgets(){
        text122 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text00);
    }

    private void setOnClickListeners(){
        text122.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(stringListCounter == 4){
                    stringListCounter =0;
                    text122.setText(" " + stringIdList[stringListCounter]);
                    stringListCounter ++;
                    setOnClickListeners();

                }
                else
                {
                    text122.setText(" " + stringIdList[stringListCounter]);
                    stringListCounter++;
                    setOnClickListeners();
                }


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Obviously I'm not doing what you're trying to do. The text will change when you press on the TextView and it will reset the onClickListener to prepare for the next press. The logic is terrible but you get an idea of how to set onClick listeners.

Also, I'm not sure why your stringIdList is an Int. wouldn't it be a list of String? It surely caused problem when setting the text of the textview since you were sending ints.

Comment: thanks fukkireta,your code is running,sorry i am beginner and i want application that i click buttons(next,previous) and textview changes and that contains not integer i want to text ...

Comment: I am new to just getting into Android myself as well, but honestly, I do my onClicks even different then any of the methods presented here.  In the XML file, one of the properties you can set for a button is onClick.  So for your button, in XML, you can add: `android:onClick="nameForYourOnClick"` all you have to do in Code is write a method like this: `public void nameForYourOnClick(View v) { //do stuff }`